# Camel XPATH choice on xmlns attribute contains

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-camel

I would like to use choice on xml namespace containing a value.

```
<Document xmlns="www.ddd.test.123.001">
 <properties>...
</Document>
```

in camel :

```java
from("direct:in")
        .choice()
            .when().xpath("/Document[@xmlns, contains(., 'test.123')]")
        .to("mock:pain:001")
```

the xmlns contain the routing value I would like to use.
Is it possible and what is the correct camel XPath string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Camel, but at in XPath 1.0 it would be

```
"/*[local-name() = 'Document' and contains(namespace-uri(), 'test.123')]"
```

You can't use `/Document` because that will only match a Document element in no namespace.

Comment: nice one! thanks, what would be the way to return the namespace value?

Comment: Just `namespace-uri(/*)`